# PCB layout for high current

Tags: power-supply, led, pcb, layout

I want to build my own wifi led controller as part of bigger project. Easiest way would be to power controller and led separately:

[image]
But I want to make it easier for end user to connect and minimize amount of wires and places where he can make a mistake:
[image]
The problem is that I don't want to transmit 2A through pcb, since I would like to avoid difficulties if possible. And here the questions:

- Is it a good practice to connect input and output terminals with wires inside controller box?
- What kind of terminal I would need to use in that case?
- Is there any standard ways to handle such problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 is definitely better. In option 2, the LED activity will 'pound' ground and possibly disrupt the wifi module.

Option 1 is called a 'star tie' power system, which isolates the supply and return currents for each module in a system.

You could make this very easy. In your diagram, move the green wire in your diagram to the other side of the wifi module and group the three pins together. Then use two identical 3-pin connectors, one for strip and one for the wifi module, plus a 2-pin connector for the power supply.

This would be pretty goof-proof as the two 3-pin connectors would be interchangeable.

Comment: Nice idea! Thanks a lot!